# How to detect referring url and link back to it on a page with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to have a custom landing page for all vistors that will show the url they are coming from and then link back to it with javascript.
I have tried the `document.refer` script but cuuldnt get along with it.

Please can you give any help?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [`document.referrer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.referrer) property. It will return an empty string if the user navigated directly to the page.

For example you could put the following link in your page that will return to the referrer:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.location.href = document.referrer;">Go back to referrer</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,
lik i have said the script will be in a landing page with a link to it referrer url and also another link to the mobile version of that same page.
For example if the detected rererrer url is example.com/shop.php
how will i code the 2nd link to lead to the mobile version i.e m.example.com/shop.php

Comment: You cannot possibly know the mobile version of a site given just an url. But you can test whether the domain name of the referrer is some known to you domain for which you know the mobile version in which case you could simply generate the proper link.

Comment: Can the code be broken down so that i will just have to put a prefix in infront so that it will lead to the mobile version?

Comment: That will depend on the site.

Comment: Yes it is exactly that way, how will the code now looks like, any help on that?

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you encountering with your code that you need help with?

Comment: <body>
welcome
<a href = "#" onclick = " window . location . href =  document . referrer ; " > view page in desktop version</a><br>
<a href = "#" onclick = " window . location . href  =  document . referrer ; " > view page in mobile</a>
</body>
if the referrer url is example.com
how will i modify the 2nd  link to make it point to m.example.com